# Comparison between TXT files

Tags: c#, text, arraylist, compare

In C# I want to make array list and store 2 text files in it. Then I want to compare another unknown file to the files in the list to see if it is the same or similar to files in array list.

First file contains:

```
312 3151 421
231 756  124
141 512  257
```

Second file contains:

```
643 151  6231
1585 645  7346
8352 67554 2532
4134.123 1523.134 676.45
```

Unknown file:

```
643 151  6231
532 511  1551 
5135 16875 6346
```

I want to to compare between the two files and find the matched file. How can I do it?

Comment: How about using string.Contains() method?

Comment: please define similar.

Comment: Please define matching criteria clearly,then only people can give you answer that you are looking for.

Comment: similar i mean the numbers in unknown x y z how similar to the another files which contains x y z it must not be all numbers are similar i want to get the best matched file which contains the same numbers not all numbers

Comment: You need to precisely define "similar".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have 2 files (or arrays) A and B that you want to compare to the X file (or array).

A base of a simple algorithm could be to:

- Iterate over the X file (or array) by reading a single line (or row)

  - For this line (or row):

    - Iterate over the A file (or array) and count the number of similar occurrences
    - Iterate over the B file (or array) and count the number of similar occurrences
- Now, having the number of matching occurences per lines (or row) per file (or array) you can chose between the A or B file (or array (!)), by preferring, for instance, the one which has the highest number of similar occurrences count.

Comment: yes , that's what i want how can i implement it ?!!

Comment: @GeorgeAlbert : The truth is out there

Comment: But how i cant implement it in c# :S